# Using generic class with protocol inheritance Getting Segmentation fault 11 error at archiving the app

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance, segmentation-fault

I have a generic base class my app. The base generic class needs a protocol in order to send messages back to the controllers.

Everything is working fine but once I try to archive the app, I'm getting **Segmentation fault: 11 compiler error**

I'm pretty new in swift as I'm coming from .net, so could be something else I missed, but I didn't find any answer about the problem yet

Here is the code how I could reproduce the issue

```
class BaseClass{
    @objc func myFunction(){

    }
}

class ClassA<T : ProtocolA> : BaseClass{
    var delegate: T?

    override func myFunction(){
        super.myFunction()

        self.delegate?.funcA?()
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA<ProtocolB>{
    override func myFunction() {
        super.myFunction()

        self.delegate?.funcB?()
    }
}

@objc protocol ProtocolA{
    @objc optional func funcA()
}

@objc protocol ProtocolB : ProtocolA{
    @objc optional func funcB()
}
```

As I see the problem is around the generic type **delegate** variable in the **ClassA**, however if the *super.myFunction()* call is commented out in **ClassB** the code build properly

Other thing I noticed that if I set the Optimization Level from **Fast, Whole Module Optimization** to **None** then I can also archive successfully

**Update 1**

I simplified the code a bit more and also I figured out if I use classes instead of protocols as generic parameter the compiler can optimize the code and working as expected

**Update 2**
Here is the compiler message

```
0  swift                    0x0000000104ae7dba PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000104ae71f6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7b8a8f5a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffeee8182e8 _sigtramp + 1928786856
4  swift                    0x00000001014b4ca8 swift::irgen::CallEmission::emitToExplosion(swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 456
5  swift                    0x0000000101613aca (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 3290
6  swift                    0x00000001015f2a80 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9152
7  swift                    0x00000001014fd4be swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1022
8  swift                    0x00000001015d28c5 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 1589
9  swift                    0x000000010145b26a performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 17018
10 swift                    0x0000000101455784 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7716
11 swift                    0x000000010140a6a8 main + 12248
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7b628145 start + 1
13 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000048 start + 2224914180
```

The error message is:

```
1.  While emitting IR SIL function "@_T012BugReproduce6ClassBC10myFunctionyyF".
 for 'myFunction()' at /Users/pal.wagner/sources/playgrounds/BugReproduce/BugReproduce/Imps.swift:20:14
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I got this working.

When I was playing around I removed all of the unnecessary (for me at least) part from the code when I got the following error

```
Using 'ProtocolB' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'ProtocolA' is not supported
```

This is the code

```
import Foundation

class BaseClass{
    @objc func myFunction(){

    }
}

class ClassA<T : ProtocolA> : BaseClass{
    var delegate: T?

    override func myFunction(){
        super.myFunction()

        self.delegate?.funcA()
    }
}

class ClassB: ClassA<ProtocolB>{

}

protocol ProtocolA{
    func funcA()
}

protocol ProtocolB : ProtocolA{
    func funcB()
}
```

So the problem seems that something about that the base class has no type for the generic type????? - WTH.

Then I tried to declare the class with the following way, which is working:

import Foundation

```
class BaseClass{
    @objc func myFunction(){

    }
}

class ClassA<T : ProtocolA> : BaseClass{
    var delegate: T?

    override func myFunction(){
        super.myFunction()

        self.delegate?.funcA?()
    }
}

class ClassB<T: ProtocolB>: ClassA<T>{
    override func myFunction() {
        super.myFunction()

        self.delegate?.funcB?()
    }
}

@objc protocol ProtocolA{
    @objc optional func funcA()
}

@objc protocol ProtocolB : ProtocolA{
    @objc optional func funcB()
}
```

So the answer is that in this case you can inherit the following way:

```
class ClassB<T: ProtocolB>: ClassA<T>
```

Anyway the compiler could give better error message when the optimization is turned on or just throw a build error